# How to use ui-select2 events

Tags: angularjs, jquery-select2, ui-select2, angularjs-select2

I am using ui-select2 as shown in the documentation:

```
<select ui-select2="{ allowClear: true}" ng-model="select2">
    <option value="one">First</option>
    <option value="two">Second</option>
    <option value="three">Third</option>
</select>
```

I would like to call some function on the controller on an event like `select2-open, select2-opening or select2-close` like this one:

```
$scope.myFunction = function(){
 alert("Hello");
}
```

How do I do that?

Comment: have you found the answer how to watch the fired events? I am particularly interested in "select2-open". I also found this question but doesn't help me solve my issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18968376/select2-event-handling-with-angular-js

Comment: Have you tried angular-ui-select? It's a pure angular port.

Comment: I came across this some time ago, but I've not given it a try yet. If you have tried it, you think it answers my question?

Comment: @Sulthan The Problem is, that angular-ui-select ist still under heavy development, it misses many features. Take a look at the roadmap https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select/wiki/Roadmap to see if you meet your requirements and do not need a fully implemented select2 port.

Answer (score 0):

I did it by adding another directive to the select2 element in which you can listen to the events.

HTML:

```
<select ui-select2="{allowClear: true}" ng-model="select2" my-directive>
    <option value="one">First</option>
    <option value="two">Second</option>
    <option value="three">Third</option>
</select>
```

Directive:

```
myApp.directive('myDirective', function() {
    return {
        link: function(scope, element) {
            element.on('select2-loaded', function() {
                // do cool stuff
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Tried this method and it didn't work for me. Do you remember what versions of AngularJS / UI-select you were using for this ?